# A problem when to use `plt.subplots()` to draw `sns.swarmplot`

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to use `plt.subplots()` with loop range to plot the `swarmplot` when feature  `plate` is different value.
SO I code it with a simple plot and it is definitely right.

```
#I just use i = 5 to specify a value
i = 5
sns.swarmplot(b[b['plate'] == 'BK0000' + str(i)]['plate'],\
              b[b['plate'] == 'BK0000' + str(i)]['tradeMoney'])
```

[image]

But there is something wrong when I try to code it as follows:

```
nrows, ncols = 64, 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(9, 72), dpi=120)

month_cnt = 1
for i in range(nrows):
    i_ = i    
    if (i < 10):
        i = '0' + str(i)

    if (i == 32 | i == 58):
        continue    

    sns.swarmplot(b[b['plate'] == 'BK000' + str(i)]['plate'],\
                b[b['plate'] == 'BK000' + str(i)]['tradeMoney'],\
                ax=ax[i_])

    ax[i_].set_xlabel('BK000' + str(i))
    ax[i_].set_ylabel('tradeMoney')
```

AND error messages puzzle me again.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        12     sns.swarmplot(b[b['plate'] == 'BK000' + str(i)]['plate'],\
>        13                 b[b['plate'] == 'BK000' + str(i)]['tradeMoney'],\
>   ---> 14                 ax=ax[i_])
>        15 
>        16     ax[i_].set_xlabel('BK000' + str(i))
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in swarmplot(x,
>   y, hue, data, order, hue_order, dodge, orient, color, palette, size,
>   edgecolor, linewidth, ax, **kwargs)    
> 2975     
> 2976     plotter =
>   _SwarmPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
>   -> 2977                             dodge, orient, color, palette)    
> 2978<     if ax is None:    
> 2979         ax = plt.gca()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in **init**(self,
>   x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, dodge, orient, color, palette)
>   1213         """Initialize the plotter."""    
> 1214
>   self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
>   -> 
> 1215         self.establish_colors(color, palette, 1)    
> 1216     
> 1217         # Set object attributes
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in
>   establish_colors(self, color, palette, saturation)
>       313         # Determine the gray color to use for the lines framing the plot
>       314         light_vals = [colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*c)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZelZ.png) for c in rgb_colors]
>   --> 315         lum = min(light_vals) * .6
>       316         gray = mpl.colors.rgb2hex((lum, lum, lum))
>       317
>
> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

And the plots are all blank.

```
b['plate'].unique()

array(['BK00001', 'BK00002', 'BK00003', 'BK00004', 'BK00005', 'BK00006',
       'BK00007', 'BK00008', 'BK00009', 'BK00010', 'BK00011', 'BK00012',
       'BK00013', 'BK00014', 'BK00015', 'BK00016', 'BK00017', 'BK00018',
       'BK00019', 'BK00020', 'BK00021', 'BK00022', 'BK00023', 'BK00024',
       'BK00025', 'BK00026', 'BK00027', 'BK00028', 'BK00029', 'BK00030',
       'BK00031', 'BK00033', 'BK00034', 'BK00035', 'BK00036', 'BK00037',
       'BK00038', 'BK00039', 'BK00040', 'BK00041', 'BK00042', 'BK00043',
       'BK00044', 'BK00045', 'BK00046', 'BK00047', 'BK00048', 'BK00049',
       'BK00050', 'BK00051', 'BK00052', 'BK00053', 'BK00054', 'BK00055',
       'BK00056', 'BK00057', 'BK00059', 'BK00060', 'BK00061', 'BK00062',
       'BK00063', 'BK00064', 'BK00065', 'BK00066'], dtype=object)
```

And I can't fix it with error messages even I have searched it before.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does BK00000 exists?  First iteration is subset returning no records?

Comment: @ScottBoston You are right sir. I have made a stupid mistake. After changing the condition of if statement to `if ((i == 0) | (i == 32) | (i == 58)):`, everything is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears during the first iteration that you are trying to do a swarmplot on an empty dataframe.  Check to make sure that BK00000 exists or skip plotting that value.